# Managed Metadata Navigation always redirecting to "start.aspx#null"

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata

I'm trying to use Managed Metadata Navigation for cruising around my site. Right now I have a couple of team sites.

In the target settings I set the navigation URL to:

```
/department/production/SitePages/Homepage.aspx
```

So far so good. But due to the MDS, the link I'm actually redirected to is (mind the `null`):

```
/department/production/layouts/15/start.aspx#null
```

which of course **should be**:

```
/department/production/layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Homepage.aspx
```

Back to the term store: I tried setting the target URL to `/department/production/` which is not a valid URL according to term store. I also tried the URL including the hash `#` but that URL also is not valid. So I'm stuck with using the above mentioned URL.

Anybody has any clue how I can set the URLs correctly without being redirected to `null`? (Sometimes it does work, when I visited the site once before it is redirecting to the correct URL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe is because Managed Metadata Navigation is actually only meant for Publishing sites (definition is in  Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation namespace), e.g. Topic pages, Friendly-pages  - not particularly tested yet, but i've only used it as such.

MSDN also states "Managed navigation APIs are built into the taxonomy and publishing libraries in SharePoint 2013. " (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163978.aspx#SP15_ManagedNav_HowManagedNavWorks)

Comment: That could very well be. Interesting. I though it could be leveraged to be the one-size-fits-all navigation... Back to custom SiteMap providers?

Comment: It depends, it is meant to be created somewhere, and used elsewhere, sort of a "global navigation", centrally administered

Comment: Well I did create it on a publishing site. There are some team sites in the navigation though...

Comment: That is not the issue, but the issue is that your links need to point to Pages/mypages.aspx (Publishing). By the way, did you tried deactivating the MDS feature in your Site Settings

Comment: Sure I could deactivate MDS and I would have normal links - but that defeats the purpose of MDS ;-) I thought there is some way I'm missing.

Comment: Next version of SharePoint :), meanwhile that is the extend i could help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to deactivate the Feature Minimal Download Strategy. When the Feature is active Links work correct if oppening another tab. Without the Feature Links always work correct